# php snippet for woocommerce price suffix error

Tags: php, woocommerce, add-filter

I am new to coding so plz excuse my idiocy!
I have added a php snippet to display a suffix after specific woocommerce products based on product ID. I found this snippet and modified it for my needs.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'nordra_text_after_price' );

function nordra_text_after_price($price){
    
    global $post;
        
    $product_id = $post->ID;
    
    $product_array = array( 11489,11485,11478,11473,11469,11465,11244 );//add in the product IDs to add text after price
    
    if ( in_array( $product_id, $product_array )) {
        
        $text_to_add_after_price  = ' / m2 '; //change text in bracket to your preferred text 
          
          return $price .   $text_to_add_after_price;
          
    }else{
        
        return $price; 
    }
          
}
```

It works for a while but then gets deactivated over and over again due to an error on this line:
$product_id = $post->ID;

I can't figure out what is wrong. Can you brains plz help me.

Googled what is wrong with line $product_id = $post->ID; but can't find anything

Comment: Well first, why do you need to move data from a perfectly good Object into a scalar variable. It serves no purpose other than unnecessary use of memory and cpu cycles

Comment: If you know the error is on that line.... How do you know this? If you are getting an error message then PLEASE show us the error message. All of the error message!

Comment: `return $price . ' / m2 ';` would also cut out unnecessary usage of a scalar variable and the CPU cycles to create it

Answer (score 0):

I not understood what you try to do and what the error but maybe it help you:
replace the lines:

```php
global $post;    
$product_id = $post->ID;
```

to line:

```php
$product_id = get_the_ID();
```